# Capturar nome do autor de um comentário a ser respondido

Tags: javascript, wordpress

No sistema de comentários do Facebook/Disqus, quando clicamos para responder a um comentário, ele coloca automaticamente na **textarea** o nome de usuário do comentário que estamos respondendo. Gostaria de saber se seria possivel fazer o mesmo com o sistema de comentários do WordPress. Ou seja, ele já permite a réplica para um usuário especifico, o que quero agora é, que quando alguém for responder um comentário, clicando no **Reply** o nome do autor desse comentário fosse colocado na **textarea**.

**Exemplo**

```js
var addComment={moveForm:function(a,b,c,d){var e,f,g,h,i=this,j=i.I(a),k=i.I(c),l=i.I("cancel-comment-reply-link"),m=i.I("comment_parent"),n=i.I("comment_post_ID"),o=k.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];if(j&&k&&l&&m&&o){i.respondId=c,d=d||!1,i.I("wp-temp-form-div")||(e=document.createElement("div"),e.id="wp-temp-form-div",e.style.display="none",k.parentNode.insertBefore(e,k)),j.parentNode.insertBefore(k,j.nextSibling),n&&d&&(n.value=d),m.value=b,l.style.display="",l.onclick=function(){var a=addComment,b=a.I("wp-temp-form-div"),c=a.I(a.respondId);if(b&&c)return a.I("comment_parent").value="0",b.parentNode.insertBefore(c,b),b.parentNode.removeChild(b),this.style.display="none",this.onclick=null,!1};try{for(var p=0;p<o.elements.length;p++)if(f=o.elements[p],h=!1,"getComputedStyle"in window?g=window.getComputedStyle(f):document.documentElement.currentStyle&&(g=f.currentStyle),(f.offsetWidth<=0&&f.offsetHeight<=0||"hidden"===g.visibility)&&(h=!0),"hidden"!==f.type&&!f.disabled&&!h){f.focus();break}}catch(q){}return!1}},I:function(a){return document.getElementById(a)}};

$("a.comment-reply-link").click(function(){
   var nome_autor = $(this).attr("aria-label").replace("Reply to ","");

   $("#respond").find("textarea").val(nome_autor);
});
```

```css
/**
 * 12.3 Comments
 */

.comments-area {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 padding: 1.6923%;
}

.comments-area > :last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.comment-list + .comment-respond {
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
}

.comment-list + .comment-respond,
.comment-navigation + .comment-respond {
 padding-top: 1.6em;
}

.comments-title,
.comment-reply-title {
 font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 line-height: 1.3333;
}

.comments-title {

}

.comment-list {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}

.comment-list article,
.comment-list .pingback,
.comment-list .trackback {
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 padding: 1.6em 0;
}

.comment-list .children {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}

.comment-list .children > li {
 padding-left: 0.8em;
}

.comment-author {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.comment-author a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
}

.comment-author .avatar {
 float: left;
 height: 24px;
 margin-right: 0.8em;
 width: 24px;
}

.bypostauthor > article .fn:after {
 content: "\f304";
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 left: 3px;
}

.comment-metadata,
.pingback .edit-link {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

.comment-metadata a,
.pingback .edit-link a {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
}

.comment-metadata a:hover,
.pingback .edit-link a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.comment-metadata a:hover,
.comment-metadata a:focus,
.pingback .edit-link a:hover,
.pingback .edit-link a:focus {
 color: #333;
}

.comment-metadata {
 margin-bottom: 1.6em;
}

.comment-metadata .edit-link {
 margin-left: 1em;
}

.pingback .edit-link {
 margin-left: 1em;
}

.pingback .edit-link:before {
 top: 5px;
}

.comment-content ul,
.comment-content ol {
 margin: 0 0 1.6em 1.3333em;
}

.comment-content li > ul,
.comment-content li > ol {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.comment-content > :last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.comment-list .reply {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.comment-list .reply a {
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 1;
 margin-top: 2em;
 padding: 0.4167em 0.8333em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.comment-list .reply a:hover,
.comment-list .reply a:focus {
 border-color: #333;
 color: #333;
 outline: 0;
}

.comment-form {
 padding-top: 1.6em;
}

.comment-form label {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: block;
 letter-spacing: 0.04em;
 line-height: 1.5;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.comment-form input[type="text"],
.comment-form input[type="email"],
.comment-form input[type="url"],
.comment-form input[type="submit"] {
 width: 100%;
}

.comment-notes,
.comment-awaiting-moderation,
.logged-in-as,
.form-allowed-tags {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.logged-in-as a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.no-comments {
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding-top: 1.6em;
}

.comment-navigation + .no-comments {
 border-top: 0;
}

.form-allowed-tags code {
 font-family: Inconsolata, monospace;
}

.form-submit {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.required {
 color: #c0392b;
}

.comment-reply-title small {
 font-size: 100%;
}

.comment-reply-title small a {
 border: 0;
 height: 32px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 26px;
}

.comment-reply-title small a:before {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

  
  <ol class="comment-list">
     <li id="comment-56" class="comment even thread-even depth-1 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-56" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a204be15ef2ea245de82edcb9798b1c1?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a204be15ef2ea245de82edcb9798b1c1?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='https://wordpress.org/' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Donald Allbright</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-56">
       <time datetime="2017-10-13T19:38:42+00:00">
        October 13, 2017 at 7:38 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=56">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Hi, this is a comment.<br />
     To get started with moderating, editing, and deleting comments, please visit the Comments screen in the dashboard.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=56#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-56", "56", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Donald Allbright'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-63" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor odd alt depth-2 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-63" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.bing.com' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>John Doe</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-63">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:20:27+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:20 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=63">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Pellentesque convallis enim at massa mattis accumsan. Suspendisse non venenatis ligula, id molestie dolor.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=63#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-63", "63", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to John Doe'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-67" class="comment even depth-3 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-67" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/03ea78c0884c9ac0f73e6af7b9649e90?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/03ea78c0884c9ac0f73e6af7b9649e90?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.google.com' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Michael</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-67">
       <time datetime="2018-03-09T14:29:48+00:00">
        March 9, 2018 at 2:29 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=67">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Integer at mauris vel tortor maximus lacinia rutrum sit amet tellus. Ut sit amet orci egestas, molestie sem eget, luctus nulla.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=67#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-67", "67", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Michael'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-68" class="comment odd alt depth-4 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-68" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/553b6227a81e80dcace42b5d8486c125?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/553b6227a81e80dcace42b5d8486c125?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn">Katia</b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-68">
       <time datetime="2018-03-09T14:30:20+00:00">
        March 9, 2018 at 2:30 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=68">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Aliquam rutrum nibh quis magna accumsan lobortis.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=68#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-68", "68", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Katia'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-69" class="comment even depth-5">
   <article id="div-comment-69" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/779a50702fdc4c3b6187643e101edfea?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/779a50702fdc4c3b6187643e101edfea?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.exemple.com' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Nietzsche</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-69">
       <time datetime="2018-03-09T14:30:48+00:00">
        March 9, 2018 at 2:30 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=69">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Praesent imperdiet eros at volutpat ullamcorper.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

       </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  <li id="comment-66" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor odd alt depth-2">
   <article id="div-comment-66" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn">Schopenhauer</b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-66">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:21:05+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:21 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=66">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>In sed suscipit justo, sed efficitur nibh. Donec imperdiet cursus sem, et convallis justo. Ut ornare rhoncus leo, ut sodales augue elementum nec.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=66#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-66", "66", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Schopenhauer'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  <li id="comment-64" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1">
   <article id="div-comment-64" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.wikipedia.org' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Gogol</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-64">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:20:39+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:20 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=64">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Maecenas fermentum enim a eros efficitur, id rutrum magna consequat.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=64#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-64", "64", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Gogol'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  <li id="comment-65" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor odd alt thread-even depth-1">
   <article id="div-comment-65" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.wikipedia.org' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Karamazov</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-65">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:20:51+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:20 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=65">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Proin non mattis purus. Proin id orci ut nibh faucibus sagittis ac varius nulla.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=65#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-65", "65", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Karamazov'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

  
 
 
  <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
  <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Reply <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>   <form action="http://localhost/wp/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate>
    <p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">Comment</label> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea></p><p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment" /> <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='1001' id='comment_post_ID' />
<input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
</p><input type="hidden" id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" value="72edf53d48" /><script>(function(){if(window===window.parent){document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name='_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';}})();</script>
   </form>
   </div><!-- #respond -->
 
</div><!-- .comments-area -->
```

Comment: @dvd Um formulário de comentário bastante comum. Nome, Email, URL e Textarea para o comentário. Cada comentário recebi uma numeração na LI `<li id="comment-64">`

Comment: @dvd Uma solução em JS, para que o nome do usuário sendo passado para a Textarea já será o suficiente, o wordpress fará o resto.

Comment: Conhece algum site que tenha isso?

Comment: @dvd Não. Só o Facebook. Rsrsrs

Comment: veja se isso resolve: https://jsfiddle.net/vqLtnk2c/

Comment: @dvd Não funcionou, coloquei um exemplo completo do sistema de comentários na pergunta.

Comment: Funcionou. Adicionei o código na sua pergunta. Executa o snippet pra vc ver.

Comment: é so aqui, ou todos os botões aparecem `admin`?

Comment: @HebertdeLima também estava acontecendo isso aqui, fiz uma modificação no exemplo adicionando nomes diferentes para ver. Também tem outra coisa que é a questão dos links que estão nos nomes, quero ver se vai funcionar.

Comment: @dvd funcionou mesmo, eu fiz uma alteração no exemplo, coloquei outros nomes e com links. Eu queria ver se seria possível passar os nomes para a textarea com os links, caso eles possuam... e também com uma tag. span ou qualquer outra. `<span class="nome-na-textarea"><a href="#link-do-usuario-respondido">João Ninguém.</a><span>`

Comment: @dvd os comentários do WordPress suportam tags. Se eu digito `<span class="nome-na-textarea"><a href="#link-do-usuario-respondido">João Ninguém.</a><span>` vai funcionar como esperando quando o comentário for postado.

Comment: Esse "nome-na-textarea" seria oq?

Comment: @dvd qualquer coisa, é apenas uma classe para controle, algo para estilizar e destacar o nome do usuário, etc.

Comment: Bora resolver isso? rs

Comment: @dvd Opa, sim, vamos. rsrs.

Comment: @dvd vamos fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seria isto: pegar o nome do autor do post e o link, e concatenar no código e enviar para o `textarea`:

```
var nome_autor = '<span class="nome-na-textarea">'
+'<a href="'
+$(this)
.closest("article")
.find("a.url")
.attr("href")
+'">'
+$(this).attr("aria-label").replace("Reply to ","")
+'.</a><span>';

$("#respond")
.find("textarea")
.val(nome_autor);
```

**Veja:**

```js
var addComment={moveForm:function(a,b,c,d){var e,f,g,h,i=this,j=i.I(a),k=i.I(c),l=i.I("cancel-comment-reply-link"),m=i.I("comment_parent"),n=i.I("comment_post_ID"),o=k.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];if(j&&k&&l&&m&&o){i.respondId=c,d=d||!1,i.I("wp-temp-form-div")||(e=document.createElement("div"),e.id="wp-temp-form-div",e.style.display="none",k.parentNode.insertBefore(e,k)),j.parentNode.insertBefore(k,j.nextSibling),n&&d&&(n.value=d),m.value=b,l.style.display="",l.onclick=function(){var a=addComment,b=a.I("wp-temp-form-div"),c=a.I(a.respondId);if(b&&c)return a.I("comment_parent").value="0",b.parentNode.insertBefore(c,b),b.parentNode.removeChild(b),this.style.display="none",this.onclick=null,!1};try{for(var p=0;p<o.elements.length;p++)if(f=o.elements[p],h=!1,"getComputedStyle"in window?g=window.getComputedStyle(f):document.documentElement.currentStyle&&(g=f.currentStyle),(f.offsetWidth<=0&&f.offsetHeight<=0||"hidden"===g.visibility)&&(h=!0),"hidden"!==f.type&&!f.disabled&&!h){f.focus();break}}catch(q){}return!1}},I:function(a){return document.getElementById(a)}};

$("a.comment-reply-link").click(function(){
   var nome_autor = '<span class="nome-na-textarea">'
   +'<a href="'
   +$(this)
   .closest("article")
   .find("a.url")
   .attr("href")
   +'">'
   +$(this).attr("aria-label").replace("Reply to ","")
   +'.</a><span>';

   $("#respond")
   .find("textarea")
   .val(nome_autor);
});
```

```css
/**
 * 12.3 Comments
 */

.comments-area {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 padding: 1.6923%;
}

.comments-area > :last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.comment-list + .comment-respond {
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
}

.comment-list + .comment-respond,
.comment-navigation + .comment-respond {
 padding-top: 1.6em;
}

.comments-title,
.comment-reply-title {
 font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 line-height: 1.3333;
}

.comments-title {

}

.comment-list {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}

.comment-list article,
.comment-list .pingback,
.comment-list .trackback {
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 padding: 1.6em 0;
}

.comment-list .children {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}

.comment-list .children > li {
 padding-left: 0.8em;
}

.comment-author {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.comment-author a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
}

.comment-author .avatar {
 float: left;
 height: 24px;
 margin-right: 0.8em;
 width: 24px;
}

.bypostauthor > article .fn:after {
 content: "\f304";
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 left: 3px;
}

.comment-metadata,
.pingback .edit-link {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

.comment-metadata a,
.pingback .edit-link a {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
}

.comment-metadata a:hover,
.pingback .edit-link a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.comment-metadata a:hover,
.comment-metadata a:focus,
.pingback .edit-link a:hover,
.pingback .edit-link a:focus {
 color: #333;
}

.comment-metadata {
 margin-bottom: 1.6em;
}

.comment-metadata .edit-link {
 margin-left: 1em;
}

.pingback .edit-link {
 margin-left: 1em;
}

.pingback .edit-link:before {
 top: 5px;
}

.comment-content ul,
.comment-content ol {
 margin: 0 0 1.6em 1.3333em;
}

.comment-content li > ul,
.comment-content li > ol {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.comment-content > :last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.comment-list .reply {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.comment-list .reply a {
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 1;
 margin-top: 2em;
 padding: 0.4167em 0.8333em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.comment-list .reply a:hover,
.comment-list .reply a:focus {
 border-color: #333;
 color: #333;
 outline: 0;
}

.comment-form {
 padding-top: 1.6em;
}

.comment-form label {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: block;
 letter-spacing: 0.04em;
 line-height: 1.5;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.comment-form input[type="text"],
.comment-form input[type="email"],
.comment-form input[type="url"],
.comment-form input[type="submit"] {
 width: 100%;
}

.comment-notes,
.comment-awaiting-moderation,
.logged-in-as,
.form-allowed-tags {
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.logged-in-as a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.no-comments {
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
 color: #707070;
 color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding-top: 1.6em;
}

.comment-navigation + .no-comments {
 border-top: 0;
}

.form-allowed-tags code {
 font-family: Inconsolata, monospace;
}

.form-submit {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.required {
 color: #c0392b;
}

.comment-reply-title small {
 font-size: 100%;
}

.comment-reply-title small a {
 border: 0;
 height: 32px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 26px;
}

.comment-reply-title small a:before {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

  
  <ol class="comment-list">
     <li id="comment-56" class="comment even thread-even depth-1 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-56" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a204be15ef2ea245de82edcb9798b1c1?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a204be15ef2ea245de82edcb9798b1c1?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='https://wordpress.org/' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Donald Allbright</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-56">
       <time datetime="2017-10-13T19:38:42+00:00">
        October 13, 2017 at 7:38 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=56">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Hi, this is a comment.<br />
     To get started with moderating, editing, and deleting comments, please visit the Comments screen in the dashboard.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=56#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-56", "56", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Donald Allbright'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-63" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor odd alt depth-2 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-63" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.bing.com' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>John Doe</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-63">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:20:27+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:20 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=63">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Pellentesque convallis enim at massa mattis accumsan. Suspendisse non venenatis ligula, id molestie dolor.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=63#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-63", "63", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to John Doe'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-67" class="comment even depth-3 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-67" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/03ea78c0884c9ac0f73e6af7b9649e90?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/03ea78c0884c9ac0f73e6af7b9649e90?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.google.com' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Michael</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-67">
       <time datetime="2018-03-09T14:29:48+00:00">
        March 9, 2018 at 2:29 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=67">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Integer at mauris vel tortor maximus lacinia rutrum sit amet tellus. Ut sit amet orci egestas, molestie sem eget, luctus nulla.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=67#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-67", "67", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Michael'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-68" class="comment odd alt depth-4 parent">
   <article id="div-comment-68" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/553b6227a81e80dcace42b5d8486c125?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/553b6227a81e80dcace42b5d8486c125?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn">Katia</b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-68">
       <time datetime="2018-03-09T14:30:20+00:00">
        March 9, 2018 at 2:30 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=68">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Aliquam rutrum nibh quis magna accumsan lobortis.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=68#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-68", "68", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Katia'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
<ol class="children">
  <li id="comment-69" class="comment even depth-5">
   <article id="div-comment-69" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/779a50702fdc4c3b6187643e101edfea?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/779a50702fdc4c3b6187643e101edfea?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.exemple.com' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Nietzsche</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-69">
       <time datetime="2018-03-09T14:30:48+00:00">
        March 9, 2018 at 2:30 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=69">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Praesent imperdiet eros at volutpat ullamcorper.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

       </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  <li id="comment-66" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor odd alt depth-2">
   <article id="div-comment-66" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn">Schopenhauer</b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-66">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:21:05+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:21 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=66">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>In sed suscipit justo, sed efficitur nibh. Donec imperdiet cursus sem, et convallis justo. Ut ornare rhoncus leo, ut sodales augue elementum nec.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=66#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-66", "66", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Schopenhauer'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
</ol><!-- .children -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  <li id="comment-64" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1">
   <article id="div-comment-64" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.wikipedia.org' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Gogol</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-64">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:20:39+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:20 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=64">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Maecenas fermentum enim a eros efficitur, id rutrum magna consequat.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=64#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-64", "64", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Gogol'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  <li id="comment-65" class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor odd alt thread-even depth-1">
   <article id="div-comment-65" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
     <div class="comment-author vcard">
      <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=56&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' srcset='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6967f6786e2387d797a02faa2b759564?s=112&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-56 photo' height='56' width='56' />      <b class="fn"><a href='http://www.wikipedia.org' rel='external nofollow' class='url'>Karamazov</a></b> <span class="says">says:</span>     </div><!-- .comment-author -->

     <div class="comment-metadata">
      <a href="http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#comment-65">
       <time datetime="2018-03-06T20:20:51+00:00">
        March 6, 2018 at 8:20 pm       </time>
      </a>
      <span class="edit-link"><a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=65">Edit</a></span>     </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

         </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

    <div class="comment-content">
     <p>Proin non mattis purus. Proin id orci ut nibh faucibus sagittis ac varius nulla.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply"><a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://localhost/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/?replytocom=65#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-65", "65", "respond", "1001" )' aria-label='Reply to Karamazov'>Reply</a></div>   </article><!-- .comment-body -->
</li><!-- #comment-## -->
  </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

  
 
 
  <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
  <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Reply <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/wp/2017/10/13/spieth-in-danger-of-missing-cut-2/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>   <form action="http://localhost/wp/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate>
    <p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">Comment</label> <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea></p><p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment" /> <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='1001' id='comment_post_ID' />
<input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
</p><input type="hidden" id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" value="72edf53d48" /><script>(function(){if(window===window.parent){document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name='_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';}})();</script>
   </form>
   </div><!-- #respond -->
 
</div><!-- .comments-area -->
```

Comment: solução magnifica. Se apenas pudesse não deixar a tag **span** e **a** não ficassem visível na textarea.

Comment: ixi, aí não tem como, porque o textarea não renderiza HTML

Comment: veja isso https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/RMNgpe

Comment: Isso é uma div editável, e não um textarea.

Comment: rsrsr compreendo, nem tinha percebido.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283553/95735

Comment: Opa! Tô vendo lá...