# Minimal Hover Menu - Da maneira certa

Tags: javascript, css, css3, menu, nav-bar

No exemplo abaixo temos um menu interessante, com um **efeito** hover, que segue o mouse e seus itens. Tudo é muito bonito e funciona bem. O problema é que esse menu está definido com dimensões padrões, não podendo adicionar mais itens ou mudar o tamanho mantendo o **efeito**.

O que eu gostaria é de ter esse mesmo **efeito** em um menu tradicional, fluido, flexível, sem dimensões definidas, sem **:nth-child**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100);
 
body {
  font-family:'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue UltraLight', Roboto, Arial, Sans-serif;
  background:#ecf0f1;
}
 
nav {
  width:400px;
  height:60px;
  margin:125px auto 0;
  text-align:center;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:0 1px 2px #ddd;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
 
nav ul {
  position:relative;
}
 
nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:60px;
  width:100px;
  margin-right:-4px;
}
 
nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-left:-4px;
}
 
li:nth-child(4):after {
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:3px;
  position:absolute;
  background:#3498db;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform:translateX(0);
  transition:.5s;
}
 
nav ul li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:nth-child(4):after { transform:translateX(100px); }
nav ul li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:nth-child(4):after { transform:translateX(200px); }
nav ul li:nth-child(4):hover:after { transform:translateX(300px); }
 
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#2c3e50;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Clients</a></li>
    <li><a>Work</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Exemplo de menu onde eu gostaria que o efeito do exemplo acima fosse aplicado.**

```css
.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
 background: gray;
 list-style: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width:auto;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
 background: #30A6E6;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 display: block;
 font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
 -o-transition: all .25s ease;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}
.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
 background: #000000;
}
#submenu {
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 35px;
 visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}
li:hover ul#submenu {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 40px; /* adjust this as per top nav padding top & bottom comes */
 visibility: visible;
}
#submenu li {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
#submenu a:hover {
 background: #DF4B05;
}
#submenu a {
 background-color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles on HTML5 & CSS3</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Difference between SVG vs. Canvas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New features in HTML5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Creating links to sections within a webpage</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Source 1:** https://codepen.io/joacimnilsson/pen/WbNLwb

**Source 2:** https://codepen.io/dhanushbadge/pen/olsvi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o JavaScript para ter o mesmo efeito. Fiz uma modificação nesta classe abaixo adicionando `position: relative`:

```
.dropdownmenu ul {
    background: gray;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

E criei uma classe que será a "barrinha" que acompanha o mouse. A barrinha será posicionada inicialmente na `li` com a classe `.current-link`:

```
.barra {
  height:3px;
  position:absolute;
  background: #00F71C;
  transition:.5s;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

O que fiz foi criar a barrinha de forma dinâmica, posicionada na primeira `<li>`. Quando o mouse passa pelas outras `li`s, a barrinha muda de posição e largura, aproveitando o efeito do `transition:.5s;`.

**Veja:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   function barPos(bar, act){
      var pos = "left:"
      +act.offsetLeft
      +"px;"
      +"width:"
      +act.clientWidth
      +"px;"
      +"top:"
      +act.offsetTop
      +"px;";
      
      bar.style.cssText = pos;
   }
   
   var lis = document.body.querySelectorAll(".dropdownmenu > ul > li"),
       act = document.body.querySelector(".dropdownmenu > ul li.current-link"),
       bar = document.createElement("span"),
       cur = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(lis, act);
       
   bar.className = "barra";
   lis[0].appendChild(bar);
   var bar = document.body.querySelector(".barra");
   
   barPos(bar, act);
   
   for(x=0; x<lis.length; x++){
      lis[x].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
         var idx = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(lis, this);
         if(cur != idx){
            cur = idx;
            bar.style.cssText = "left:"
            +this.offsetLeft
            +"px;"
            +"top:"
            +this.offsetTop
            +"px;"
            +"width:"
            +this.clientWidth
            +"px;";
         }
      });

      lis[x].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
         cur = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(lis, act);
         barPos(bar, act);
      });
   }
   
   window.addEventListener("resize", function(){ barPos(bar, act); });
   
});
```

```css
.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
 background: gray;
 list-style: none;
 width: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width:auto;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
 background: #30A6E6;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 display: block;
 font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
 -o-transition: all .25s ease;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}
.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
 background: #000000;
}
#submenu {
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 35px;
 visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}
li:hover ul#submenu {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 40px; /* adjust this as per top nav padding top & bottom comes */
 visibility: visible;
}
#submenu li {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
#submenu a:hover {
 background: #DF4B05;
}
#submenu a {
 background-color:#000000;
}

.barra {
  height:3px;
  position:absolute;
  background: #00F71C;
  transition:.5s;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles on HTML5 & CSS3</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Difference between SVG vs. Canvas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New features in HTML5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Creating links to sections within a webpage</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="current-link"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: simplesmente magnifico. é exatamente isso!  O efeito está fixado no link **Home** esse efeito também deverá ficar ativo na página do respectivo link aberto. `li.current-link`

Comment: entendi o que preciso fazer.

Comment: fiz confusão, julguei mal o código, tentei, mas não consegui...

Comment: ficou perfeito.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285555/95735

Comment: será que é possível colocar também esse mesmo efeito, com o e evento **focus** ? igual o do css.

Comment: a questão do focus/active para esse menu, seria necessário fazer uma nova pergunta?

Comment: não funciona, também testei com mousedown, e só funciona o click. Mas o hover não. Não dá para utilizar esses valores juntos? `mouseover` e `mousedown`

Comment: Aqui funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/q488npqp/

Comment: inclusive o hover? Porque aqui só funciona o clique.

Comment: Farei outra pergunta.

Comment: Compreendo. De fato, mas o principal é apenas o contextmenu. `Abrir em nova aba.`

Answer (score 1):

John seguindo todas as regras que vc falou eu consegui chegar nesse resultado.

O exemplo usa FlexBox então é bem responsivo. vc pode acrescentar quantos itens quiser que vai ajustar direitinho *(Talvez vc tenha que diminuir a fonte um pouco se tiver itens de mais...)* Mas no mais funciona bem em telas menores até certo ponto.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/800/600);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
.box {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0f0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 350ms;
}
.box:hover::after {
    background-color: #0f0;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

.link {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="box">
        <a class="link" href="">item 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a class="link" href="">item 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a class="link" href="">item 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a class="link" href="">item 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <a class="link" href="">item 5</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**OBS:** o único detalhe é que a animação não fica sempre acompanhando o mouse. Mas se quiser vc pode fazer ela começar no "centro" dos `.Box`, basta colocar `transform-origin: center;` pra vc ver como fica.

Comment: Sua solução é boa, mas eu preferiria não usar flexbox, se for possível gostaria apenas de colocar esse efeito, no menu do segundo exemplo, tal como ele é, aquele menu é bem feito, funciona em todos os navegadores, inclusive no ie7... sei que o efeito só vai funcionar nos navegadores modernos...